# Certificates store windows 10 C#

Tags: c#, certificate, windows-10, x509certificate, certificate-store

I am asking this because I am desperate and I couldn't find any post talking about this problem anywhere.

In my WinForms C# application I am using the following code to retrieve Windows Certificates:

```
X509Certificate2Collection Certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

//Filtering the list, showing only not-expired ones
Certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
store.Close();
```

This works like a charm on every Windows version, from Windows XP to Windows 8.1. In Windows 10 it works on the first attempt. If I do it again, it gets stuck waiting.

I tried to implement a "timout timer" of 60 seconds: the provided piece of code just gets timed out.

If the user removes his USB-key (or smartCard) that contains the certificate from the PC and inserts it again, the problem is solved.

Does anyone have a solution for this behaviour? I am desperate, my customers upgrading to windows 10 are mad with me and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Is your smart card compatible with Windows 10?

Comment: Of course, otherwise it would not work the first time! The first time i use that code i get the certificates, select one and i use it to digitally sign a file or to authenticate the owner. NO problems. But the second time i run that code i just get stuck waiting forever. ONLY on Win10.

Comment: Does it happen with different smartcard? What smartcard are you using? It could be a fault in smartcard middleware.

Comment: "Of course, otherwise it would not work the first time!" it doesn't say anything. The card may work (sometimes), but it was not tested by vendor, thus, this scenario will not be supported. We had various issues with eToken Pro tokens where they failed under certain circumstances on modern OS versions. Support said that this OS is not yet supported and got support with special patch to resolve these issues in newer OS.

Comment: @pepo Yes, it happens with multiple devices, but in my country the most used device type is usbKey with certificate on it.

Comment: @FabioLamberti Try to enable logging of the smartcard middleware. Maybe there will show something that will help you. You could also enable CAPI2 eventlog (event viewer->windows logs->application and service->microsoft->windows->CAPI2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this Windows 10 bug. It is actually a "workaround" but 100% works and cause no issues.

The workaround is to create a "global" X509Store store in your application, and NEVER close it. You just open the first time you need (Or at startup of your app) and never call "store.Close();"

You can call store.Certificates.Find(....) during all the session of your application, and it will never show the issue that happens if you close the store and re-open again. 
Maybe is not a beautiful solution, but works 100%.
I hope this will help who, like me, found this damn win10 bug.